MAUI .Net8 IOS: Asset validation failed (90704) Missing app icon
I'm using MAUI on VS 17.9.6 / .net8 to develop a multi platform IOS-Android app.
I've got the stage where I'd like to publish the application in the IOS appstore, but when I upload it with Transporter I get this validation error:

Asset validation failed (90704) Missing app icon. Include a large app
icon as a 1024 by 1024 pixel PNG in the asset catalog of apps built
for iOS, iPadOS, or watchOS. Without this icon, apps can't be
submitted for review.

If I look at the Info.plist file in the application bundle, using the plutil tool, I see the following in there:
"CFBundleIcons" => {
    "CFBundlePrimaryIcon" => {
      "CFBundleIconFiles" => [
        0 => "appicon60x60"
      ]
      "CFBundleIconName" => "appicon"
    }
  }
  "CFBundleIcons~ipad" => {
    "CFBundlePrimaryIcon" => {
      "CFBundleIconFiles" => [
        0 => "appicon60x60"
        1 => "appicon76x76"
      ]
      "CFBundleIconName" => "appicon"
    }
  }

If I then look at the above mentioned .png files in the application bundle, they're all very small. BTW, these PNGs are generated by MAUI from SVG files configured in the project as follows:
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#000000" BaseSize="1024,1024"/>

How do I generate a large enough appicon and then have it included in the Info.plist file by the MAUI build process? I've tried to manually modify the Info.plist file based on what I've found here, but that didn't work for me. The solution seems to be Xamarin specific.
I've looked at varios MAUI docs (including this MS page) but I couldn't find anything related in there.

Does this help? ITMS-90704: Missing App Icon or have you tried on a default MAUI project?

I've managed to get past this issue. An important additional detail is that I was generating the .ipa archive from the command line, using a command like the one below. I ran this from the home folder of my Visual Studio project.
dotnet publish -f net8.0-ios -c Release -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64 -p:ServerAddress=192.168.x.x -p:ServerUser=xxxxx -p:ServerPassword=xxxx -p:TcpPort=58181 -p:_DotNetRootRemoteDirectory=/Users/xxxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotn 
et/ -p:CodesignKey="iPhone Distribution: xxxxxx" -p:CodesignProvision="xxxxx"

The generated .ipa file, when uploaded to the Apple Store using Transporter would fail validation with the error message mentioned in my question.
I was using the command line as a workaround, as the "publish" feature in VS 17.9.6 was not working for me. Whenever I tried to publish, I'd see a message on screen saying "No archive builds available", so I was kinda stuck.
I've then installed VS 17.10 preview, where the publish feature seems to work again. The upload to the store is still failing with some cryptic error though...
To overcome this last issue, I've managed to upload my app to the Appstore by logging into my Mac and looking for the archive folder, typically located in /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives.
Once you've located the archive (.xcarchive folder) you want to upload, select "Open With... Xcode". From there, you'll be able to validate the app and then upload it. This requires pre-configuring you Apple distribution profile in Xcode. To do that, I've created an empty iOS app with Xcode and configured my Apple Dev and Distribution profiles.


I encountered this issue with Xamarin.iOS, what worked was just to unplug the test iPhone from my Mac, then close VS, reopen and rebuild the project. The .ipa would then appear in the bin\iPhone\Ad-Hoc folder (or whatever your config for distribution builds is) instead of in the device-builds folder, and would be about half a Mb larger. Uploaded using Transporter and delivered fine. Possibly what is happening is that when it detects a test device connected it strips out assets that aren't necessary for deploying to it for testing, even if it's a distribution build, and the App Store icon is one of those.
I haven't built a Maui app yet but possibly this workaround would work there too.
